# 2D vector arrays in c++

Tags: c++

This program launches, but when entering data, it throws an error (In visual studio: Expression: Vector subscript out of range)
I must be doing something wrong, but I'm very new at vector arrays, so I'm trying to learn them ;)
Also, I would like to know, what loop condition to using, when the size of the vector array is unknown (it may vary)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> v; // 2D vector array
    string stri; // Input Data

    for (auto i = 0;; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0;; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter array's " << i << " and " << j << " element:";
            cin >> stri;
            v[i][j] = stri;
        }
    }
    for (auto i = 0;; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0;; j++)
        {
            cout << v[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems. First, the vectors are not initialized. By default, vectors have 0 elements, so when you try to acces `v[i][j]`, it will complain that it is out of range. Second, there is no condition to exit the loops, making the loops infinite. Assuming that you know the size of the arrays in advance, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t n = 4;
    size_t m = 3;
    vector<vector<string>> v(n, vector<string>(m)); // 2D vector array
    string stri; // Input Data

    for (auto i = 0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j<v[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter array's " << i << " and " << j << " element:";
            cin >> stri;
            v[i][j] = stri;
        }
    }
    for (auto i = 0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j<v[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << v[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

If you do not know the size in advance and you want the user to decide, try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<string>> v; // 2D vector array
    string stri; // Input Data

    for (auto i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        v.emplace_back();
        for (auto j = 0; ; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter array's " << i << " and " << j << " element (Enter 'End' to end the row): ";
            cin >> stri;
            if(stri == "End")
                break;
            v[i].push_back(stri);
        }
        cout << "Do you want to add another row? [y/n] ";
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        if (c == 'n')
            break;
    }
    for (auto i = 0;i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0;j<v[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << v[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a response, but if there's the unknown size? It is possible or it must be known?

Comment: @Raicha You need to come up with a way for the user to communicate how many elements they wish to provide, or a way to indicating that enough input has been provided. Otherwise, you will just keep taking input forever.

Comment: @Raicha As Francois said, the approach of entering data won't be the same, but it can be done. I suggest taking a look at [std::vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

Comment: I tried the push_back. But there was problems with that.
Only think it allowed was v[i][j].push_back((char)stri))
But only 1 char isn't quite nice :D

Comment: you just want `v[i].push_back(stri)`

Comment: @Raicha I added a simple example of creating the vectors dynamically using the input of the user. There are other ways to do it that are less cumbersome, like asking for the size beforehand, but I think you have all the necessary information to do it on your own from this point.

Comment: Thank you all guys ;) You are so kind

Answer (score 1):

So v in your code is a vector of vectors. Then this line in your code:

```
v[i][j] = stri;
```

is only OK if the following is true:

- the vector v has a size larger than i, so that it is OK to use v[i]
- the vector v[i] has a size larger than j, so that it is OK to use v[i][j]

You can use the `resize` function to set the size of a vector. If you modify your code like this, adding two `resize` calls, then your code can succeed to use the vector a few times, but only until the size has been reached:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<vector<string>> v; // 2D vector array
  v.resize(5);
  string stri; // Input Data

  for (auto i = 0;; i++)
    {
      v[i].resize(5);
      for (auto j = 0;; j++)
        {
          cout << "Enter array's " << i << " and " << j << " element:";
          cin >> stri;
          v[i][j] = stri;
        }
    }
}
```

The above program survives until the size 5 is reached, then it anyway does not work anymore. It is anyway a strange program since the loops are infinite; i will remain zero and j will just increase forever (or in practice until the vector size is reached).